# $x^n+px+q$ has at most two or three roots

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} :x \mapsto f(x)=x^{n}+px+q$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0,1\}$. Show that this polynomial can have at most two real roots if $n$ is even, and at most three real roots if $n$ is odd.

My attempt: $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+p=0$ only if $x=( \frac{-p}{n})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$. Suppose $n$ is even. Then this root is well defined as $n-1$ is odd and so possibly $f$ has a maximum/minimum in $x$, so that $f$ could have a root to the left of $x$ and to the right of $x$. Suppose that there is a third root inbetween these two roots; according to Rolle's theorem this can't be true unless the root is in $(\frac{-p}{n})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ but then the two other roots cannot exist as there is already a maximum/minimum in this point.

Is this reasoning correct? And could someone help me to get started on the problem if $n$ were odd? Because I don't really see it. Thank you!

Comment: By roots, you must be implying real roots, I suppose?

Comment: Yes indeed, I will edit right away

Comment: This also follows from Descartes' rule of signs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}+p$ has at most one real root if $n-1$ is odd and at most two real roots if $n-1$ is even.   So if $n$ is even, $f(x)$ has only one critical point, so it can cross the $x$-axis only twice.   Similarly if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track so far: if $n$ is even there is exactly one turning point, and by Rolle's theorem there must be a turning point between every two consecutive real roots, so there can be at most two real roots.

If $n$ is odd, can you see why there are at most two turning points?